# How do I use calendar.leapdays() with in a function to return how many leap years there are within a given list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to make a function that returns the number of leap years within a list of years. How do I use the module correctly?

leapdays needs two arguments to work so I'm not sure how to have it reference the list or if leapdays is even correct to use in this function.

```
import calendar 

def LYcount(listYears):
    return calendar.leapdays(listYears) """leapdays needs two arguments to work
                                           so I'm not sure how to have it 
                                           reference the list or if leapdays is 
                                           even correct to use in this 
                                           function"""

# expected output: 2
print(LYcount([2001, 2018, 2020, 2090, 2233, 2176, 2200, 2982]))

# expected output: 4
print(LYcount([2001, 2018, 2020, 2092, 2204, 2176, 2200, 2982]))

# it currently returns TypeError: leapdays() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y2'
```

Comment: Why don't you use `isleap(year)` within a list comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `leapdays(year1, year2)` which returns the number of leap years within a year range, I'd suggest using `isleap(year)` within a list comprehension.

```
import calendar

def LYcount(listYears):
    return len([year for year in listYears if calendar.isleap(year)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another function from calendar isleap. It will be useful when your year list does not have the years in a range.

```
import calendar


def checkLeapYear(input_year_list):
   for year in input_year_list:
      if calendar.isleap(year):
        print("{} is leap".format(year))

input_year = [2001,2009,2020,2016,2003,2010]

checkLeapYear(input_year)
```